# Using static members of child class in parent class based on arguments

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I want to use the same static data memebers in multiple classes and make one parent class from which I can call the variable from specific class based on the argument. Please refer the code.

For the below code, my requirement is if I call

`Test.x` giving some sort of argument say `Test1` or `Test2`, it should get me the value from the respective class. Can someonne help me with this??

I don't want to use `Builder()`, `CSV`, or instantiate the class. Is there anyother solution for this?

```
Class Test() {
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int z;
}

Class Test1() {
    static int x = 1;
    static int y = 2;
    static int z = 3;
}

Class Test2() {
    static int x = 4;
    static int y = 5;
    static int z = 6;
}
```

Comment: make your parent as `abstract` class or make override and set the values in child class.

Comment: why did you choose to make the variables static?

Comment: Java class syntax is `class ____ {` not `Class ____() {`

Comment: If the requirements force you to use static members, to avoid creating objects, and to pass the name of a class as a parameter, those requirements are stupid.

Comment: @MohamedSaligh - I think that will work. I can use interface and declare the variable and create classes for different values implementing the interface and while instantiating, i can just refer the interface to the class I want based on simple if-else. I think that will work. Please let me know what you think. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are several issues with static and inheritance.

A class based custom configuration is best done **declarative**, in data (properties, XML),
but it can be done in code. The base class can hold a map of all children's
configuration.

```
class Base {

    private static Map<Class<T extends Base>, Config> configByClass = new HashMap<>();

    protected Base(Supplier<Config> configProducer) {
        // Could do in constructor:
        configByClass.merge(getClass(), (oldk, k) -> {
            if (oldk == null) {
                return configProducer.get();
            }
        });
    }

    protected final Config getConfig() {
        // Could do lazy in getter
        configByClass.merge(getClass(), (oldk, k) -> {
            if (oldk == null) {
                return configProducer.get();
            }
        });
        return configByClass.get(getClass());
    }
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    public Child1() {
        super(() -> {
            Config config = new Config(1, 3, 4);
            ...
            return config;
        });
    }

    void f() {
    }
}
```

Calling the config supplier *inside* the constructor has one tiny pitfall: the child class fields are still unavailable, but you did not want to use individual objects anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class test{
  static int a;
  static int b;
  static int c;
  
  
  //to use the values of test1 class do this
  a = test1.a;
  b = test1.b;
  c = test1.c;
  
  
  //to use the values of test2 class do this
  a = test2.a;
  b = test2.b;
  c = test2.c;
}

public class test1{
  static int a = 1;
  static int b = 2;
  static int c = 3;
}

public class test2{
  static int a = 4;
  static int b = 5;
  static int c = 6;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Using this approach will increase the lines of code. I want a simple solution but have to keep in mind the code length also